# Authentification with Windows Auth NTLM

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, ntlm

There is a WebAPI hosted in IIS. It is using Windows authentification with NTLM protocol only. If I am trying to reach it with chrome extension which gives me the ability to send REST requests, chrome prompts me for credentials and this is the part I dont understand why? Windows auth is the one that should take my information from my windows login isnt it? It is not forms auth. Of course it happens the first time only, if you are reaching it multiple times it just returns the token, but I guess its just the session things.

I feel that I am missing something and dont have enough knowledge about it so any information would be nice.

Question:
Why windows auth is prompting for credentials when I am trying to authenticate to my WebAPI the first time? Shouldnt it handle this automatically based on my windows login information?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication means it will validate the username and password of the user available in the directory listing of the hosted server.
And after you enter the credentials once then the browser will manage it further.
If you close that tab and open the url in new tab then also it will not prompt again unless the browser is not closed and reopened.

It is not possible to handle windows login automatically without login prompt box.